# Android 2.2 vs later not handling connectivity manager the same

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-wifi

I have two dev devices one an android 2.2 phone and the other a Nexus7 tablet (no phone).
Both have wifi.  If the code below is executed on the 2.2phone it detects whether Wifi or Mobile Data is on and working.  If I put the same code on the Nexus7 tablet it returns that there is no internet connection even though wifi is on. What do I have to do to make it work on both devices?

```
   public boolean isOnline()
   {
ConnectivityManager connMgr =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
   }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3283828/1012284NetworkAvailability check returns false yet the phone is online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isConnected will return true when the WIFI connection is established to a router. Are you sure you have the connections setup exactly the same on both of the devices?

you could also try isConnectedOrConnecting() which is pretty much the same except it returns true even when a connection is not yet established to the ISP but in the process of being established.

Also check if maybe some of the permissions have changed for jelly Bean for allowing you to check for connectivity.

Other than that i see no reason for this method to act differently on different devices.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are some bugs with `ConnectivityManager`.  It looks like it's a documented bug without a fix for it yet:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11891

Otherwise I worked on an app earlier this year that listened for network changes.  You could try `networkInfo.getTypeName()`, that will return 'WIFI', or 'null' (will also return 'MOBILE' for data networks).  You could try going off of this condition.  I used that line earlier this year for a broadcast receiver to monitor network changes and it has worked from 2.2 - 4.0.4 (have not tested on 4.1 yet).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem lay elsewhere. The code posted above was working, however I was getting a Java error and its said cant write to HEAD. I didnt need to so I commented out. 
The code worked OK without throwing an error under 2.2 but throws a JAVA error  under 4.1. Glad I have devices to test on, emulator would not have caught this. Was compiled for 2.2. Wow.

```
   File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
   URL u = new URL(url);
   HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
   c.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
// c.setDoOutput(true);   //<<< Allowed on 2.2 Not on 4.1
   c.connect();
   InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
   long dt=c.getLastModified();
```